# On rendering Item. item contain value but item.name is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I Pushed My API responseJson to arrayholder

on Flatlist I using my Arrayholder as Data

```
data={this.state.arrayHolder}
renderItem={({ item, index }) =>{
console.log(item);
console.log("Name:"+item.name);

}



 ConsoleLog:
    {name:bob,Class:123},{name:Hulk,Class:234}
    Name:undefined
```

my Item Working Find, But Item.Name is Undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not correct 
It should be {name:'bob',Class:'123'},{name:'Hulk',Class:'234'}
Else it will treat name's assigned value as variable

Example expo: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/listview2

Comment: How To Change that In array

Comment: can you post the data which you are assigning in this "arrayHolder"

Comment: My responseJson is[object object] i converted my responseJson To JSON.Stringfy(responseJson) so My output is Like  this {"UserName":"Dina","gender":"Male"}

Comment: You need to push fetched data into an array 
---------------- 
createArray(){
  var fetchedData = {name:'bob',Class:123};
  this.state.dataLoaded.push(fetchedData);
} -----------------------
** Check this link ----------->>> https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/listview2